# react reusable components error (es6)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

constantly getting these two errors in console:

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or >number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite >components). Check the render method of `Embedded`.
>
> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: >expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite >components) but got: object. Check the render method of `Embedded`.

what i'm trying to do is have my `Embedded` class contain many `Prop` classes within it.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Prop extends React.Component {
 constructor () {
  super();
 }
 
    render() {
     console.log(this);
        return <span> I am a { this.props.position } </span>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Prop position="developer"/>, document.getElementById('prop-passed'));
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Prop from './prop.jsx';


class Embedded extends React.Component {
 
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
 
  render() {
    let lines = this.props.sentences.map((item) => {
      return <li key={ Math.random(1, 5) }><Prop position={ item.position }/></li>
    });

    return (
      <div>
      { lines }
      </div>  
    );

  }
}
 
ReactDOM.render(<Embedded sentences={[ { id: 1, position: 'dog' }, { id: 2, position: 'cat' }, { id: 3, position: 'bear' }]}/>, document.getElementById('embedded'));
```

EDIT:

i've essentially removed the lines at the bottom of each snippet i provided earlier and created another file to put there instead but I am still getting the same errors.

i don't want to put all my classes in the same file because i would like them separate and easier to find when I need to look for them again.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Simple from './simple.jsx';
import Prop from './prop.jsx';
import Embedded from './embedded.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<Simple/>, document.getElementById('simple'));
ReactDOM.render(<Prop position="developer"/>, document.getElementById('prop-passed'));
ReactDOM.render(<Embedded sentences={[ { id: 1, position: 'dog' }, { id: 2, position: 'cat' }, { id: 3, position: 'bear' }]}/>, document.getElementById('embedded'));
```

Comment: works fine here...http://jsfiddle.net/vhuumox0/15/

Comment: @JordanHendrix thanks for helping me out so quickly. i actually have these in two separate files. could it be because of the last line `ReactDom.render...` that's causing these errors?

Comment: yea you should just put them in one file like that, you only need one ReactDom.render.

Comment: @JordanHendrix if you still have some time to check this out, i've updated my original post with some of the changes. i even added another render to your jsfiddle you provided to see if it was possible (which worked) but i still see the same errors with those changes in my project. any ideas?

Comment: The error means that `Prop` is `undefined`. Looking at the two files it doesn't seem you are exporting the components. You can only import what you export.

Comment: @FelixKling tyvm. that did it!

Answer (score 0):

Jordan and Felix helped me on to the right track.

- I kept my files (Embedded.jsx, Prop.jsx) separated.
- I removed the last line from each file `ReactDom.render(...)` and put them into another file.
- Went back to both files and on the last line of each, I just `export default` the class.

Now everything is working properly.